# Counting the occurrence of specific words in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column `Token` that contains a string of words.
For the string in column `Token` in each row of the dataframe I would like to count the amount of times certain words occur.

Input:

```
0    ['uno', 'dos', 'one', 'two', 'tres', 'quatro',...
1    ['uuh', 'sugar', 'pie', 'honey', 'bunch', 'kno...
2    ['cant', 'get', 'satisfaction', 'cant', 'get',...
3    ['woke', 'mornin', 'mind', 'mind', 'got', 'tro...
```

and a bunch more rows, but this is the format

I have a list of words that i want to check for

```
words = ["uno", "dos"]
```

i tried doing the following

```
def counter(row):
    return len([key for key, val in enumerate(row) if val in set(words)])

df.apply(lambda row: counter(['Token']), axis =1)
```

however, this results in the wrong outcome, with zero for each row.

expected output:

```
0   4
1   5
2   2
3   1
```

How do I correctly apply this function to each element of the row, or what other function would do the trick.

Comment: show input and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply lambda` on 'Token' and then find occurence of word in a string using `string.count()`. Need to do this for every word so use `list comprehension`

```
words = ["uno", "dos"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Token":["uno dos khela uno dos","ha ama kau a","aa uno"]})
df["Token_count"] = df.Token.apply(lambda x: sum([x.count(word) for word in words]))
print(df)   

                       Token      Token_count
    0  uno dos khela uno dos            4
    1           ha ama kau a            0
    2                 aa uno            1
```

Answer (score 1):

Question not well defined, taking a guess here:

```
words = ["uno", "dos"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Token": ["A uno dos", "B dos tres", "C tres"]})

df["count"] = df.Token.apply(lambda row: len([x for x in words if x in row]))

print(df)

# Output:
        Token  count
0   A uno dos      2
1  B dos tres      1
2      C tres      0
```

Your main issue appears that you are passing `['Token']` to the `Counter` function, which doesn't make sense, because like this you are checking whether the `words` are included in the String `"Token"`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work except it only counts each word in the 'words' list once, i want to count how many times those words are in the row