# How to extract the top N rows from a dataframe with most frequent occurences of a word in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, count

I have a Python dataframe with multiple rows and columns, a sample of which I have shared below -

| DocName | Content |
| --- | --- |
| Doc1 | Hi how you are doing ? Hope you are well. I hear the food is great! |
| Doc2 | The food is great. James loves his food. You not so much right ? |
| Doc3. | Yeah he is alright. |

I also have a list of 100 words as follows -

```
list = [food, you, ....]
```

Now, I need to extract the top N rows with most frequent occurences of each word from the list in the "Content" column. For the given sample of data,

> "food" occurs twice in Doc2 and once in Doc1.
>
> "you" occurs twice in Doc 1 and once in Doc 2.

Hence, desired output is :

```
[food:[doc2, doc1], you:[doc1, doc2], .....]
```

> where N = 2 ( top 2 rows having the most frequent occurence of each
> word )

I have tried something as follows but unsure how to move further -

```
list = [food, you, ....]
result = []

for word in list:
    result.append(df.Content.apply(lambda row: sum([row.count(word)])))
```

How can I implement an efficient solution to the above requirement in Python ?

Comment: Please show some of your own effort to implement a solution.  Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Have updated the question with my initial attempt.

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67385186/counting-the-occurrence-of-specific-words-in-a-dataframe) may point you in the right direction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second attempt (initially I misunderstood your requirements): With `df` your dataframe you could try something like:

```py
words = ["food", "you"]
n = 2  # Number of top docs
res = (
    df
    .assign(Content=df["Content"].str.casefold().str.findall(r"\w+"))
    .explode("Content")
    .loc[lambda df: df["Content"].isin(set(words))]
    .groupby("DocName").value_counts().rename("Counts")
    .sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index(level=0)
    .assign(DocName=lambda df: df["DocName"] + "_" + df["Counts"].astype("str"))
    .groupby(level=0).agg({"DocName": list})
    .assign(DocName=lambda df: df["DocName"].str[:n])
    .to_dict()["DocName"]
)
```

- The first 3 lines in the pipeline extract the relevant words, one per row. For the sample that looks like:

  ```
     DocName Content
  0    Doc1     you
  0    Doc1     you
  0    Doc1    food
  1    Doc2    food
  1    Doc2    food
  1    Doc2     you
  ```
- The next 2 lines count the words per doc (`.groupby` and `.value_counts`), and sort the result by the counts in descending order (`.sort_values`), and add the count to the doc-strings. For the sample:

  ```
           DocName  Counts
  Content                
  you      Doc1_2       2
  food     Doc2_2       2
  food     Doc1_1       1
  you      Doc2_1       1
  ```
- Then `.groupby` the words (index) and put the respective docs in a list via `.agg`, and restrict the list to the `n` first items (`.str[:n]`). For the sample:

  ```
                     DocName
  Content                  
  food     [Doc2_2, Doc1_1]
  you      [Doc1_2, Doc2_1]
  ```
- Finally dumping the result in a dictionary.

Result for the sample dataframe

```
  DocName                                                              Content
0    Doc1  Hi how you are doing ? Hope you are well. I hear the food is great!
1    Doc2  The food is great. James loves his food. You not so much right ?
2    Doc3  Yeah he is alright.
```

is

```
{'food': ['Doc2_2', 'Doc1_1'], 'you': ['Doc1_2', 'Doc2_1']}
```

Comment: This is amazing Timus, thank you so much. If I were to attach the counts along with the doc name, how can I do that ? For example - {'food': ['Doc2 _2', 'Doc1_1'], 'you': ['Doc1_2', 'Doc2_1']}

Comment: @dravid07 See the edit (one additional line after resetting the index is adding the counts to the `DocName` column).

Comment: Thanks a ton Timus. The consise Pythonic code is so beautiful to look at :) I hope I can be at that level some day haha !!

Comment: By the way, is there any way that I can connect with you Timus ?

Comment: @dravid07 Thanks for the feedback, I'm glad you like it. What do you mean by connect: Something like LinkedIn?

Comment: Yeah Linkedin would be nice.

Comment: @dravid07 I have an email address in my profile here. You could send me a link to your LinkedIn profile, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this problem can be broken down into two sub-problems:

1. Get the frequency of words per "Content" cell
2. For each word in the list, extract the top N rows

Luckily, the first sub-problem has many neat approaches, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20510768/count-frequency-of-words-in-a-list-and-sort-by-frequency). TLDR use the Collections library to do a frequency count; or, if you aren't allowed to import libraries, call ".split()" and count in a loop. But again, there are many potential solutions

The second sub-problem is a bit trickier. From our first solution, what we have now is a dictionary of frequency counts, per row. To get to our desired answer, the naive method would be to "query" every dictionary for the word in question.
E.g run

```
doc1.dict["food"]
doc2.dict["food"]
...
```

and compare the results in order.

There should be enough to get going, and also opportunity to find more streamlined/elegant solutions. Best of luck!